# UTF-16 to UTF-8 using ICU library

Tags: utf-8, utf-16, icu

I wanted to convert UTF-16 strings to UTF-8. I came across the ICU library by Unicode. I am having problems doing the conversion as the default is UTF-16.
I have tried using converter:

```
UErrorCode myError = U_ZERO_ERROR;
UConverter *conv = ucnv_open("UTF-8", &myError);
int32_t bytes = ucnv_fromUChars(conv,   target, 0, (UChar*)source, numread, &myError);
char *targetLimit = target + reqdLen;
const UChar *sourceLimit = mySrc + numread;
ucnv_fromUnicode(conv,&target, targetLimit, &mySrc, sourceLimit, NULL, TRUE, &myError);
```

I get bytes as -(big random number)
and garbage at the original target location

What am i missing?

Comment: Forgot to mention that UTF-16 is expected in Little endian or Big endian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a best practice to check for errors after calls that specify a UErrorCode parameter. I would start there.

Something like...

```
if (U_FAILURE(status)) 
{
    std::cout << "error: " << status << ":" << u_errorName(status) << std::endl;
}
```